# Request to reopen too broad question about standard/best practice for dealing with discovered ancillary patterns not hypothesized

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, too-broad

A couple of days ago I asked the question on main 
[When conducting a study, what is standard practice with patterns you find along the way?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413294/when-conducting-a-study-what-is-standard-practice-with-patterns-you-find-along) and it was put on hold earlier this morning as 'too broad'.

I am requesting here hints on how to address this (and any other problems) so that people will vote to reopen.

Can anyone suggest what about it is so broad and how to reduce the broadness?

I realize it may not be clear (most questions on CV.SE are mathematical and so a statistical practice question may be a little vague). I think I can make the question more precise with an example. But I'm not sure exactly how the question is too broad. Are there just too many possible answers? Are there any other things I can do to make the question answerable?

Comment: I think the main problem is that the answers depend less on statistics and more on other scientific approaches, and depend on the nature of the patterns you find. Ultimately it's just not something that can be addressed in a SE-length answer.

Comment: I think it's both an interesting topic of discussion and completely unsuitable for CV, unfortunately. How one ought to deal with this would differ not just by field, but also by type of study (experiment/observation), possibility and cost of obtaining new data, nature & complexity of the analysis that turned up such a pattern, the strength of the pattern, the financial/social/scientific implications of the pattern, and more. You have not really constrained any of these possibilities in your question, and even if you had, a general answer might be hard to provide.

Answer (score 4):

[Trying to rectify my frequent mistake of posting comments instead of answers]

I think it's both an interesting topic of discussion and completely unsuitable for CV, unfortunately. How one ought to deal with this would differ not just by field, but also by type of study (experiment/observation), possibility and cost of obtaining new data, nature & complexity of the analysis that turned up such a pattern, the strength of the pattern, the financial/social/scientific implications of the pattern, and more. You have not really constrained any of these possibilities in your question, and even if you had, a general answer might be hard to provide.